# Do php shortcode on page load

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a shortcode that takes a while to return all the queries and therefore makes the page slow to load. I would like to load the page, with a placeholder. Something like this. I doubt its possible but worth a shot, as it would be an intensive task to write the queries using jquery.

Something along the lines of

```
<div id="my-widget">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          success: function(data) {
                .html('<?php echo myshortcode; ?>');
            }
            $('#my-widget').html(div);           
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: PHP code is interpretted before the response is returned from the server, not afterwards. So what you're suggesting would not work.  What might work would be to make an AJAX request to request the data on page load, and to append the response to the `body` accordingly.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Just let your shortcode output the HTML and the javascript (when you've written working javascript code, that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Solution for your problem could be to shorten the query and only request basic things you need to display the page.
Another Solution would be the background request over ajax, so you would craft another site in the background whichs then replaces a body tag :

```
$.get( "ajax.php?page=index", function( data ) {
    $("body").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Why would I need to replace the whole body tag? Can I not just do what you suggest, but only replace a div? For example  $.get( "ajax-get-function.php", and then paste all of php in file ajax-get-function.php ?

Comment: Its only an example Sure you can Put it wherever you like